# Selenium: XPATH breaks if contains '

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script that saves weapon names, and then later tries to grab elements using the same names.
This works for all guns until they have a ' in their name.

When this happens, the wait condition fails.
I feel like this is probably due to different encodings of the character that mismatch between the browser and what python dictionaries store.

If I have a line like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-hash-name='"+gun["name"]+"']")))
listing = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*//*[@data-hash-name='"+gun["name"]+"']")[0]
```

How can I fix this so that it can handle 's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-hash-name="'+gun["name"]+'"]')))
listing = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*//*[@data-hash-name="'+gun["name"]+'"]')[0]
```

As your value also has singlequotes change the enclosing quote as double

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass strings into XPath in this way

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@data-hash-name="{}"]""".format(gun["name"]))))
listing = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*//*[@data-hash-name="{}"]""".format(gun["name"]))[0]
```

Comment: Could `gun["name"]` contain a double quote? This would fail for the same reason. String formatting is *not* a safe way to generate an XPATH expression, just like it's not a safe way to construct a SQL query.

Comment: Gun name is Chantico's

Comment: @chepner It's not a generic solution for all possible issues with quotes, so yes, if for some reason gun name will contain double-quote it won't work. But OP claimed about issue with single quote only

Comment: @Hint33 Please add more details about "did not work"? Do you still get a SyntaxError or TimeoutError?

Comment: TimeoutError, sorry. Same issue as I originally had, therefore didn't work